# Using a column in one mandatory and one optional foreign key in hibernate ORM

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, database-design, orm

I want to use a field in one optional and one mandatory composite foreign key within one entity.

I have three different entities, `Team`, `Person` and `Shard`. Persons belong to a team ManyToOne. Both entities have a `ShardID`, which is a FK to `Shard`.

All teams and persons have IDs that are only unique per shard, but they will also only reference the other entities with the same shard ID. Their ShardID is part of their Primary key.

```
Shard
---
PK       ID
UNIQUE   Name
```

```
Team
---
PK, FK1   ShardID
PK        ID
---
FK1 (ShardID -> Shard)
```

```
Person
---
PK, FK1, FK2   ShardID
PK             ID
FK2            TeamID
---
FK1 (ShardID -> Shard)
FK2 (ShardID, TeamID -> Team)
```

Additionally, the `Person` -> `Team` relationship is optional. A `Person` may not be member of a `Team`, and this may change over time.

In trying to model the `Person` object in JPA, I run into a problem. Obviously, when I model both the `ShardID` as part of the primary key and as a foreign key column, hibernate gives me the `Repeated column in mapping for entity` error. I can prevent this using `insertable = false, updatable = false`:

```java
    // This contains the shard_id column
    @EmbeddedId
    protected PersonId id;
    
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "shard_id", insertable = false, updatable = false), 
        @JoinColumn(name = "team_id", nullable = true)
    })
```

But I cannot do this because hibernate requires all `JoinColumns` to have identical settings for `insertable` and `updatable`, and I need the ability to add a team to the person later down the line. `ShardID` will always be present, but `TeamID` may not be.

How can I achieve this in hibernate JPA ORM? I've browsed the hibernate docs for O/R modeling and can't find a way. I've been looking at table inheritance, but that feels very unnatural and doesn't fix the "optional problem".

*This example does not contain my actual data model, but serves as a simplified example.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `@JoinColumnOrFormula` like this:

```
@JoinColumnOrFormulas({
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "shard_id", referencedColumnName = "shard_id")), 
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true))
})
```

Comment: This solution would be Hibernate specific, correct? I couldn't find an implementation of Hibernate's `JoinFormula` that takes a 'name' attribute and doesn't require a `value` attribute, so I tried with `shard_id` as the `value`. I also had to specify `referencedColumnName = "id"` on the `JoinColumn`. This doesn't create the foreign key relationship in database, but may allow me to use the object if the structure already exists.

Comment: Yeah this is Hibernate specific as JPA doesn't support this. I corrected the typos.